# Postgres Upgrade from 11.16 to 14.4

Tags: database, amazon-rds, postgres-14, postgres-11

We are trying to upgrade our AWS RDS postgres version 11.16 to max allowed latest version 14.4
Now that we are skipping and jumping directly to 14. Is it a good idea? any issues we should look out for or any major changes? the release documents has lot of information, What things we need to look for?

Comment: The optimizer was improved in version 12. I would consider this a good thing, but queries can perform differently. Bottom line: I would check heavy queries. How metadata is reported also changed, but this doesn't affect normal queries. I would say that the upgrade should go smoothly as long as you test it in lower environment well in advance.